# Parse Laravel exception using regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am trying to parse the Laravel log for exceptions (and other types of messages) using the [JackieDo/Laravel-Log-Reader](https://github.com/JackieDo/Laravel-Log-Reader), however, there is a problem with getting the exception data.

The input string is:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Classes\Storage\AbstractStorage::formatBytes() must be of the type int, null given, called in /app/app/Classes/Storage/PlexStorage.php on line 152 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to App\\Classes\\Storage\\AbstractStorage::formatBytes() must be of the type int, null given, called in /app/app/Classes/Storage/PlexStorage.php on line 152 at /app/app/Classes/Storage/AbstractStorage.php:88)
```

And the resulting array must look like this (or something along those lines):

```
[
    'message'       =>  'Argument 1 passed to App\\Classes\\Storage\\AbstractStorage::formatBytes() must be of the type int, null given',
    'exception'     =>  'Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError',
    'in'            =>  '/app/app/Classes/Storage/PlexStorage.php',
    'line'          =>  152
]
```

However, the regular expression, which is build by the following piece of code:

```
$pattern = "/^" . self::CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_PATTERN . self::CONTEXT_MESSAGE_PATTERN . self::CONTEXT_IN_PATTERN . "$/ms";
preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
```

Where:

```
const CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_PATTERN   = "exception\s\'{1}([^\']+)\'{1}";
const CONTEXT_MESSAGE_PATTERN     = "(\swith\smessage\s\'{1}(.*)\'{1})?";
const CONTEXT_IN_PATTERN          = "\sin\s(.*)\:(\d+)";
```

And the result of execution of this piece of code is:

```
/^exception\s\'{1}([^\']+)\'{1}(\swith\smessage\s\'{1}(.*)\'{1})?\sin\s(.*)\:(\d+)$/ms
```

is not working (matches are always empty).

I am not even close to be able to work with this kind of regex strings (only able to write simple regex strings), so any help in solving this issue is really appreciated.

**P.S.** I dont think asking the developer is a good idea since the project seems to be abandoned (last update is almost from a year ago, but the main portion of the package is working just fine.

**P.P.S.** This is the complete method to extract necessary information from the log

```
    public function parseLogContext(string $context): array {
        $content = trim($context);
        $pattern = "/^" . self::CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_PATTERN . self::CONTEXT_MESSAGE_PATTERN . self::CONTEXT_IN_PATTERN . "$/ms";
        preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
        $exception = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : null;
        $message   = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[3] : $content;
        $in        = isset($matches[4]) ? $matches[4] : null;
        $line      = isset($matches[5]) ? $matches[5] : null;
        return compact('message', 'exception', 'in', 'line');
    }
```

Comment: As the exception message itself can contain exceptions as well, I would try to split the log entry on `called in` and `on line` for example. It seems easier and quicker than a regex in my opinion.

Comment: I wonder if I could trouble you not to add salutations into questions? Questions are for posterity here, and succinct technical writing is broadly an expectation. Meta references are available on request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
/((.*?),\scalled\sin\s(.*?)\son\sline\s(\d+).*?{"exception":.*?\((.*?)(?=(?:\(|\))))/gis
```

- Group 1: **message**
- Group 2: **in**
- Group 3: **line**
- Group 4: **exception**

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/dZBb3K/4